# C# - How to add a string of single unspaced digits individually to a list?

Tags: c#

I'm very new at C#, so hello! I've tried finding this solution elsewhere but it's escaping me.

So I currently have a string full of digits. They are not separated by spaces. I'm trying to add each digit in that string to a list of integers. Example below:

```
string digits = "1100001";
List<int> binaryList = new List<int>();
// code to add each digit to the list
// example, binaryList[0] = 1, binaryList[1] = 1, binaryList[2] = 0, etc
```

I've not been able to find anything that works. I was also wondering while we're converting if there was any way to group the same digits together into the list? This is more curiosity than the main objective. Example below:

```
string digits = "1100001";
List<int> binaryList = new List<int>();
// code to add each group of same digits to the list
// example, binaryList[0] = 11, binaryList[1] = 0000, binaryList[2] = 1 etc
```

Thank you!

.

EDIT: So what I've tried so far is fairly cut and paste, but I just get errors. I don't know enough about C# to make educated guesses around them.

So I tried .AddRange

```
binaryList.AddRange(digits);
```

but that throws up an error, so I tried .Add by itself

```
binaryList.Add(digits);
```

but that gives me a similar error. I have an older piece of code I used to add a string with spaces to a list, but removing the space from the Split or removing Split entirely doesn't seem to work.

```
var binaryList = digits.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

## My final solution

To any future people reading this wanting my solution, thanks to all the answers below I got two efficient ways of doing it. I'll write the whole code out with each solution.

The first solution, using foreach

```
string digits = "1100001";
List<int> binaryList = new List<int>();

foreach (var index in digits)
{
 binaryList.Add(int.Parse(index.ToString()));
}
```

And the second solution, using AddRange

```
string digits = "1100001";
List<int> binaryList = new List<int>();

binaryList.AddRange(digits.ToCharArray().ToList().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToList());
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, Try posting some code and then post where are facing the problem. SO is not a platform where your entire problem will be solved like this.

Comment: Oh, okay! The only issue is I'm not sure at all how to approach it. I've only tried fairly cut-and-paste solutions from other projects/SO posts. Thanks for the feedback, I'll edit what I've tried in.

Comment: Think about it from this perspective.  You've tried things, but aren't sure why they didn't work.  If you show us, we can explain, and show the correct way.  This is a more effective way of learning.

Comment: I post a solution for your first problem, check it

Comment: That makes a lot of sense as an approach. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For your first problem

```
public List<int> BinaryList(string digits)
{
    List<int> binaryList = new List<int>();

    foreach(var index in digits)
    {
        binaryList.Add(int.Parse(index.ToString()));
    }

        return binaryList;
}
```

Call

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string digits = "1100001";
       int result = BinaryList(digits)[0];
       MessageBox.Show("" + result);
}
```

Comment: Oh, awesome! It took me a good while to figure out how to apply it to my code, sorry hah. I was so lost. In the end I extracted the 'foreach () {}' in your first snippet of code and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it hehe.
I'm working with the second problem

Comment: Oh, don't really worry about the second problem if you don't want. Now that I can do the application into a list, I can come up with a solution to grouping them as I move on with my task. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In this specific case it's a conversion from an incoming binary message. My task is to convert it based on groupings of the digits. It's a little strange, I know! It's part of my course on C# - hence the fact I'm only a beginner haha

Comment: I have been working on the second problem in spite of everything and could not get anything because it turns out that when grouping the numbers in the array, these are converted to integers, since the BinaryList is integer, but it turns out that being integers, the program rounds them, that is, instead of 0000 it would have 0, so the way to get the 4 zeros is returning string, for that reason, I do not see any way to solve your second problem

Comment: Thank you so much, Hector. Your perseverance is awesome. And that's good to know. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var d in digits) binaryList.Add(int.Parse(d));
```

Comment: This gave me an error, but when I added .ToString() to d in (int.Parse(d)) - like Hector's code, it worked. It helped me to see which part of Hector's and your code was applicable, and I understand how I can use foreach for this in future now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
binaryList.AddRange(digits.Select(digit => int.Parse(digit.ToString())));
```

Comment: Ah, so that's how you use AddRange to achieve this. This also works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Strings in .Net are collections of chars so you can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) to simplify your code (although some may argue this is less readable).

```
  string digits = "1100001";
        List<int> binaryList = digits.Select(d => Convert.ToInt32(d.ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: Strings are a collection of chars? I definitely didn't know that, thanks! And this works perfectly too. Thank you for your help! I'm adding all of these solutions to my vocabulary :)